# Can't retrieve data from SQL Server

Tags: c++, sql-server, odbc

ALL,

First things first. My environment:

- Windows 8.1
- MSVC 2010 Pro
- SQL Server 2005 (came with Windows)
- ODBC driver that came with the Windows

Now to the problem.

I'm trying to execute a following query:

```
"SET NOCOUNT ON; DECLARE @TargetDialogHandle UNIQUEIDENTIFIER; 
"DECLARE @EventMessage XML; ";
"DECLARE @EventMessageTypeName sysname; ";
"WAITFOR( RECEIVE TOP(1) @TargetDialogHandle = conversation_handle, @EventMessage = CONVERT(XML, message_body), @EventMessageTypeName = message_type_name FROM dbo.EventNotificationQueue ), TIMEOUT 1000;";
"SELECT @EventMessageTypeName AS MessageTypeName, @EventMessage.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/TSQLCommand/CommandText)[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS TSQLCommand, @EventMessage.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/ObjectName)[1]', 'varchar(128)' ) as TableName";
```

Here is the code (error handling omitted for simplification; the code is compiled in UNICODE mode):

```
SQLWCHAR *columnData[3];
for( ret = SQLFetch( m_hstmt ); ( ret == SQL_SUCCESS || ret == SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO ) && ret != SQL_NO_DATA; ret = SQLFetch( m_hstmt ) )
{
    ret = SQLGetData( m_hstmt, 1, *columnDataType[0], columnData[0], *columnDataSize[0], &messageType );
    ret = SQLGetData( m_hstmt, 2, *columnDataType[1], columnData[1], *columnDataSize[1], &sqlCommand );
    ret = SQLGetData( m_hstmt, 3, *columnDataType[2], columnData[2], *columnDataSize[2], &name );
}
```

Executing the query inside the Server Management Studio, I see all 3 columns being retrieved correctly with the clear text.

When I tried to run the code above, only column 1 and 2 have the text. Column 3 data has some garbage (columnData[2] contains some Chinese characters).

However when I turned on logging for the ODBC DM in Windows everything is retrieved correctly:

```
docview         1ac4-142c    EXIT  SQLFetch  with return code 0 (SQL_SUCCESS)
    HSTMT               0x34A4AC98

docview         1ac4-142c    ENTER SQLGetData
    HSTMT               0x34A4AC98
    UWORD                        1
    SWORD                       -8 <SQL_C_WCHAR>
    PTR                 0x0D782EF8
    SQLLEN                   128
    SQLLEN *            0x3FE8F610

docview         1ac4-142c    EXIT  SQLGetData  with return code 1 (SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO)
    HSTMT               0x34A4AC98
    UWORD                        1
    SWORD                       -8 <SQL_C_WCHAR>
    PTR                 0x0D782EF8 [     128] "http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQL/Notifications/EventNotificatio\ 0"
    SQLLEN                   128
    SQLLEN *            0x3FE8F610 (128)

    DIAG [01004] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]String data, right truncation (0)

docview         1ac4-142c    ENTER SQLGetData
    HSTMT               0x34A4AC98
    UWORD                        2
    SWORD                       -8 <SQL_C_WCHAR>
    PTR                 0x0D886FF8
    SQLLEN                  2048
    SQLLEN *            0x3FE8F604

docview         1ac4-142c    EXIT  SQLGetData  with return code 0 (SQL_SUCCESS)
    HSTMT               0x34A4AC98
    UWORD                        2
    SWORD                       -8 <SQL_C_WCHAR>
    PTR                 0x0D886FF8 [      32] "DROP TABLE test;"
    SQLLEN                  2048
    SQLLEN *            0x3FE8F604 (32)

docview         1ac4-142c    ENTER SQLGetData
    HSTMT               0x34A4AC98
    UWORD                        3
    SWORD                        1 <SQL_C_CHAR>
    PTR                 0x0C0AEEF8
    SQLLEN                   128
    SQLLEN *            0x3FE8F5F8

docview         1ac4-142c    EXIT  SQLGetData  with return code 0 (SQL_SUCCESS)
    HSTMT               0x34A4AC98
    UWORD                        3
    SWORD                        1 <SQL_C_CHAR>
    PTR                 0x0C0AEEF8 [       4] "test"
    SQLLEN                   128
    SQLLEN *            0x3FE8F5F8 (4)
```

MSVC project declares "UNICODE" symbol, but the column in question is retrieved as SQL_C_CHAR and not SQL_C_WCHAR.

What is going on here? Can someone shed some light? Should I pass SQL_C_WCHAR into SQLGetData() to receive proper value?

TIA!

Answer (score 0):

According to the trace you are passing SQL_C_CHAR for the column type to SQLGetData for column 3. That would be why that is the format for that column.

Comment: yes, I use SQL_C_CHAR, because SQLDescribeCol() returned SQL_VARCHAR/SQL_CHAR for the type. I will test tonight if I have to use SQL_C_WCHAR even if this case.

Comment: The type passed to SQLGetData is the type of the buffer being stored to not the type of the data on the DB side.An ODBC driver is required to either translate when the two do not match or produce an error. SQLDescribeCol is correct when it says the type is VARCHAR but that is irrelevant since you are storing to an SQLWCHAR buffer.

Comment: I re-read the documentation and it looks like you are correct. Thank you.